# Relative link from readme.md to another file in package, rendered in npmjs

Tags: npm, markdown

I've created an npm module which is hosted on npmjs.com.

Due to the structure of the module, I've split the documentation into a general `readme.md` and then more specific files which are linked to from the main `readme.md`:

```
.
├──documentation
│   ├── doc1.md
│   └── doc2.md
└── readme.md
```

The links in `readme.md` look like this: `[some text](documentation/doc1.md)`. They work perfectly fine locally and in their CodeCommit repo (and I suspect it would be fine in github as well).

However after publishing it to npm, the links become `https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentation/doc1.md`, which of course is an invalid URL and leads to a 404 error.

I've tried to figure out how to get a valid url to the file in question so I can create links that lead to it, but I can't even find out how to get a direct link to the file in the package. It may also be worth noting that the package itself is a private organisation package, but I've tried the same thing on a test public package and had the same issue there, so I don't think it's relevant.

Does anyone know how to link from the root `readme.md` file to another file in the same package, in a way that works in npmjs?

Comment: I've tried `/absolute/path` and `relative/path` and neither work. I've given up and just used the full github url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the issue at [npm community](https://npm.community/t/relative-links-in-npm-readme-markdown-not-functional/1525) they say that it's solved, so I tried for my self to see what went wrong?

And they were right, I've missed some points so I'll write all the required steps:

1. Make sure your repository at github/gitlab is public
2. Make sure in your package.json file you have the proper [repository](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#repository) configuration that point at your repo correctly

Example:

```json
{
  ...
  "repository": {
    "url": "https://github.com/lalosh/js-library-boilerplate",
    "type": "git"
  }
  ...
}
```

3. When doing the relative linking you need to include the relative path from your repo root, including the `.md` suffix.

Example:

```
We can [link](documentation/sub-doc.md) to an inner relative file
```