# Are full absolute paths in links inside markdown files of GitHub repositories inevitable if we want to publish the package to npm?

Tags: github, npm, markdown

Assume that we have the GitHub repository with below 2 Markdown files:

- README.md
- Documentation/SampleDocumentationPage.md

From the **README.md** we can refer to **SampleDocumentationPage** by relative path or shortened absolute path:

```
See [sample documentation page](Documentation/SampleDocumentationPage.md)
```

If we publish the package to NPM, the **README.md** will displaying on package's main page which has below URL.

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/$SCOPE_NAME$/$PACKAGE_ID$
```

Will link to **SampleDocumentationPage.md** in **README.md** work?
I suppose no, because correct absolute path of **SampleDocumentationPage.md** is

```
https://github.com/$USER_NAME$/$REPOSITORY_NAME$/blob/master/Documentation/SampleDocumentationPage.md
```

while in relation to **npm** the computed URL of **SampleDocumentationPage.md** is

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/$SCOPE_NAME$/$PACKAGE_ID$/Documentation/SampleDocumentationPage.md
```

Something possible to do with it except the usage of absolute paths only?
The absolute paths in Markdown could be very long like:

```
<dl>

  <dt><a href="https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Arrays/getArrayElementSatisfiesThePredicateIfSuchElementIsExactlyOne/getArrayElementSatisfiesThePredicateIfSuchElementIsExactlyOne.md">getArrayElementSatisfiesThePredicateIfSuchElementIsExactlyOne</a></dt>
  <dd>Returns the element of specified array matching with the predicate if such element is exactly one, otherwise error will be thrown or null will be returned (depending on dedicated option's value).</dd>

  <dt><a href="https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/Yamato-Daiwa-ES-Extensions/blob/master/CoreLibrary/Package/Documentation/Arrays/getLastElementOfNonEmptyArray/getLastElementOfNonEmptyArray.md">getLastElementOfNonEmptyArray</a></dt>
  <dd>Returns the last element of array, herewith <b>UnexpectedEventError</b> will be thrown if target array is empty.</dd>

</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you are not restricted to absolute links!  I'm not sure at what point it happens, but I believe NPM rewrites your relative links to absolute links to your repository, if the repository info is supplied in the `package.json`.

I made an example package so you can see it in action:

- The Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csandman-relative-readme-links
- The Raw README so you can see the relative link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/csandman/csandman-relative-readme-links/main/README.md

Answer (score 2):

Please check these:

[Relative link from readme.md to another file in package, rendered in npmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575382/relative-link-from-readme-md-to-another-file-in-package-rendered-in-npmjs)

Here it is reported as npm issue and added to backlog

[Relative links in markdown are broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72630497/are-full-absolute-paths-in-links-inside-markdown-files-of-github-repositories-in)

You can find some solutions here, try and see which works for you.

[Relative links in markdown README not being rewritten on npmjs.org](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown/issues/432)

Try [marky-markdown](https://github.com/npm/marky-markdown) is a markdown parser, written in NodeJS, that aims for parity with GitHub-style markdown. It is built on top of markdown-it, a CommonMark markdown parser.

[remark-relative-links](https://www.npmjs.com/package/remark-relative-links): Rewrites absolute URLs to relative ones with remark